# Как с помощью CSS выбрать определенный элемент с классом?

Tags: css, css3

Допустим на странице несколько `div`'ов. С классом или без.
И есть несколько `div`'ов с классом `.class-name`, положение которых в документе неизвестно. 
Но нужно выбрать первый (или второй, третий, четвертый…) `div` с классом `.class-name` из общего количества.

С помощью CSS это можно как-то сделать?

Думал получится с `.class-name:nth-of-type(n)`. Но в этом случае приходится вручную указывать положение из общего количества всех `div`'ов. А хотелось бы указывать его исходя из количества дивов с классом .`class-name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: aqua;  
}

/* для 1 блока */
.class-name{
    background: blanchedalmond;
}
.class-name ~ .class-name{
  background: aqua;
}

/* для 2 блока
.class-name ~ .class-name {
    background: blanchedalmond;
}
.class-name ~ .class-name ~ .class-name{
  background: aqua; 
}
*/

/* для 3 блока и т.д
.class-name ~ .class-name ~ .class-name{
    background: blanchedalmond;
}
.class-name ~ .class-name ~ .class-name ~ .class-name{
  background: aqua; 
}
*/
```

```html
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div class='class-name'>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div class='class-name'>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div class='class-name'>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div class='class-name'>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div class='class-name'>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div class='class-name'>div</div>
<div>div</div>
```

Comment: Это подразумевает соседство div и только в этом случае будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, но работает только для первого div'a.

Comment: @A. Gusev в каком случае это не будет работать?

Comment: @soledar10 Извините, вопрос дополнил.

Comment: для выбора 2( 3 и выше) по счету блока с соот. классом условие выбора измениться, но его также можно выбрать

Comment: @soledar10 Выглядит как костыль :) Спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

Вы в правильном направлении думаете. 
Просто кроме псевдокласса nth-of-type есть также first-of-typee и last-of-type, которые выбирают первый и последний элемент, соответственно. 
Для Вашего случая применимо правило .class-name:first-of-type {}

Comment: Это не работает - [jsfiddle.js](https://jsfiddle.net/d7LcLscw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, это невозможно средствами CSS. `nth-of-type`, `nth-child` и т.д. не фильтруют по классу а работают ориентируясь только на порядковый номер элемента относительно родителя вне зависимости от классов.

Только средствами jQuery возможно применять селектор `:eq`.

Ещё есть вариант добавить класс или CSS свойство с помощью Javascript.

Comment: что за порядковый номер элемента родителя? кто в этом случае родитель?

Comment: исправил формулирование, спасибо. Имел ввиду порядковый номер элемента относительно родителя.

Comment: Жаль. Надеялся что все таки есть способ.